# ampps/Laravel5: error:Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I install laravel 5.2 on Ampps (windows 10) with [this tutorial.](http://www.ampps.com/wiki/Installing_Laravel_Framework)

it works.

But Now I want connect to mysql.

I create a 'test1' DB and change these two files:

**config/database.php**

```
mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test1'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

**.env**

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=test1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

After that I restart apache.

then in CMS I run this code:

```
F:\Ammps\www\quickstart>php artisan migrate
```

But I get this error:

> ```
> error SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
> ```

I think I miss a step.

can please help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Ampps FAQ](http://www.ampps.com/wiki/Category:FAQs#How_to_use_AMPPS) you need the default mysql password:

```
1. Default MySQL root password is "mysql".
```

So add that to your .env file like this:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=test1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mysql
```